# SkiaSharp installation causes app to crash onload

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I've followed this really helpful blog post (https://blog.xamarin.com/drawing-with-skiasharp/) to install SkiaSharp 1.60.0 to present SVG images in an app.  Once the necessary packages are installed, and all compiles, when I launch the app it crashes within the LoadApp method.

Uninstalling all the SkiaSharp nuget packages, then all works fine again, but of course no SVG support!  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, think this is the key - I needed to be really specific about the packages to install in each project, and to ensure that the versions are consistent.  Posting this here to help others in need!

So the key is to be clear about which specific packages from nuget are needed in which project.  The PCL requires SkiaSharp, SkiaSharp.svg (for SVG support) and SkiaSharp.View.Forms (for Xamarin.Forms support).  The platform specific projects require all of these and SkiaSharp.View which will install platform specific libraries in each.

It's also important to ensure that the version of each package is consistent between the packages *and* between projects.  The root of the problem I had was that 1.60.3 was installed automatically in the PCL and 1.60.0 in the platform specific projects.  This caused the app to crash on load.  Downgrading the PCL to 1.60.0 fixed the issue.  Probably upgrading all to the latest version would also work as well.